# making NeoComplCache show the same matches like omnicomplete

Tags: vim

I am tring to set up autocomplete (intellisense) in VIM. For this I am using the NeoComplCache plugin, which works, but it does not show all entries that <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> shows. For instance, NeoComplCache doesn't show any newly created functions, variables, or classes, whereas as omnicomplete shows them just fine.

I have this in my _vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1
let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1
let g:neocomplcache_min_syntax_length = 1
```

Is there a way to tell NeoComplCache to show the those entries as well so that Vim's default <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> items show?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. I use SPF-13 and didn't have line 1. I was wondering why it wasn't omnicompleting.

Answer (score 0):

```
if !exists('g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns') 
    let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns = {} 
endif 

let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.php = '[^. \t]->\h\w*\|\h\w*::'
```

from [neocomplcache.txt](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache/blob/master/doc/neocomplcache.txt) I think this might work.